# Name conflict in Haskell while creating modules

Tags: haskell, module, namespaces

In the following code I had to use `elem'` instead of simply `elem`, because prelude already has a function `elem`, how could I use `elem` while declaring Tree module, avoiding conflicts??

```
module Tree(Tree(..), singleton, insert, elem') where

data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)

singleton :: a -> Tree a
singleton a = Node a Empty Empty

insert :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
insert e Empty = singleton e
insert e tree@(Node e2 left right)
  | e == e2 = tree
  | e > e2 = Node e2 left (insert e right)
  | e < e2 = Node e2 (insert e left) right

elem' :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Bool
e `elem'` Empty = False
e `elem'` (Node e2 left right)
  | e == e2 = True
  | e > e2 = e `elem'` right
  | e < e2 = e `elem'` left
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the `Prelude` module is in scope by default, this can be overridden.  Any module that does *not* explicitly import `Prelude` has an implicit `import Prelude` at the start; however, if you explicitly import the Prelude, then this isn't added.  Thus, you can import `Prelude` except for `elem` by using `hiding`:

```
import Prelude hiding (elem)
```

In the context of your code, this is

```
module Tree(Tree(..), singleton, insert, elem) where

import Prelude hiding (elem)

data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)

-- ...

elem :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Bool
e `elem` Empty = False
e `elem` (Node e2 left right)
  | e == e2 = True
  | e > e2 = e `elem` right
  | e < e2 = e `elem` left
```

If you still need to refer to `Prelude.elem`, you can always add an extra `import qualified Prelude` line, too.

For more on module imports, see [the Haskell Wiki's nice summary of `import`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Import), including the various options for how to import modules and a bit about (suppressing the) implicit `Prelude` import.

---

(Of course, although you're generally unlikely to need it, the final arbiter for modules is [the Haskell 2010 report, Ch. 5](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html/haskellch5.html); [§5.3](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-1010005.3) is on import syntax, [§5.5](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-1070005.5) is on name conflicts, and [§5.6](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-1110005.6) is on the `Prelude` (including [§5.6.2](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-1130005.6.2), "Shadowing Prelude Names").

Comment: Something I find a bit annoying of the `hiding` solution is that it may happen that GHC warns you that the `import` is useless when it is **not**. However when you get the warning it means you should simply use the `NoImplicitPrelude` extension for that file. Still it sounds like buggy behaviour for GHC. It should never state that an import is useless if it has a non-empty `hiding` clause where at least a name `n` is defined in the imported module and also in the current module.

Comment: I've read the the **Haskell Wiki article** you shared and it is really clarifying, so just to complete, to solve the problem and still access _Prelude's elem_ one solution could be: 
`import Prelude hiding (elem)`
`import qualified Prelude (elem)`. This way I could still access Prelude's `elem` but only through `Prelude.elem`, the other Pelude functions remain the same...